# Convert string to time and add some minutes

Tags: javascript

I have a form and one button to plus some minutes to a time(hh:MM), but the time is a span tag.

At Firefox works well, but when I tested at Chrome doesn't work the Date(). What happened?

```
//Botão adicionar horário agenda.
$('.button').click(function() {
  var $duration_schedule = $('#duration');
  var duration = $duration_schedule.val(); // 30
  var hour = $('.time_schedule_form').text(); // 10:00
  var new_time = self.Plus_minutes(hour, duration);
  alert(new_time); // 10:30
});


Plus_minutes: function(hour, duration) {
    var time, new_hour, hours = '';
    time     = new Date("T"+hour); // Erro at Chrome
    time.setTime(time.getTime() + duration*60000);
    hours     = time.getHours().toString();
    minutes   = time.getMinutes().toString();
    if (minutes.length > 1) {
        new_hour = hours + ':' + minutes;
    } else {
        new_hour = hours + ':0' + minutes;
    }

    return new_hour;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that it is happening because of constructor's input! In case of time you should put numbers in milliseconds. The Data Object have those constructors bellow:

- new Date();
- new Date(value);
- new Date(dateString);
- new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,milliseconds]]]]]);

you can take at look at [Developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) then you can check a better explanation about formats.

Maybe the Firefox are converting to including something in that part of code. I found out other explanation about Data input formats, you can take a look too at: [Convert String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for UTC would be like 2013-02-27T17:00:00Z (Z is for Zulu Time). Append Z if not present to get correct UTC datetime string.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using `setMinutes` to update using `getMinutes`.

```
newdate.setMinutes(newdate.getMinutes() + 10);
```

Comment: My real problem occours when I convert the string to Date. time = new Date("T"+hour); that doesn't work at Chrome.